# find value in a.txt , put it as an input in b.txt using batch

Tags: batch-file, input, pointers, cmd

I am looking for your help on the following.

I am going to read a value in a.txt, and put it as an input for b.txt
The problem is, in a.txt, the value will keep changing due to iteration process. So, it is better to point a pointer to WHERE the value will appear. 
Ex. (as in a.txt file)

```
X = 12345
```

so, i would like to point where is X, and then read the value next to X, put it as input to b.txt.

I hope that it is possible using batch file in Windows command prompt.

---

Sorry guys, i guessed my explanation is not enough. Let me try again.
Let say i have a file a.dat, b.dat

In file a.dat,

```
x = 12345
```

In file b.dat

```
y = 54321
```

The position of the line in both files is the same for every execution (with other application that is not batch/ms-dos)

I want to pick up the value in a.dat of 12345 , which is next to x, that replace the value in b.dat, which is 54321 with 12345, so that in b.dat will be as follow.

```
y = 12345
```

My questions are,

1. How can i point the value next to "x = ", and than put this value in b.dat next to "y = "?

I hope that is explained. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by "input for b.txt"? Txt files don't require "input" as they are not executable....

Comment: How would you go about doing it manually?   I mean, how would you identify the line you want to find?

Comment: show how those input files look like, then show how you want b.txt to look like in the send

Answer (score 0):

If your file `a.txt` doesn't change in size, your best option is to save the line number where the thing you're looking for is.